# ‘A less smart student’

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, comparison

My sentence is

> A less student would take the first approach.

Here I have no intention to compare. What I mean is a not so smart student.

Is my sentence okay?

Answer (score 2):

We don't use *less* like that.

You either need to add an adjective after "less" - *a less studious student*, *a less talented student*, *a less adventurous student* - or you need to substitute the word *lesser*.

A *lesser student* would mean *a worse student*, but it sounds stilted, old-fashioned, or just unnatural.